# Material Image List Error: @import "@material/feature-targeting/functions";

Tags: angular, sass, material-components-web

I want to use mdc-image-list in my Angular project. I'm getting an error:

```
@import "@material/feature-targeting/functions";
       ^
      Can't find stylesheet to import.
   ╷
21 │ @import "@material/feature-targeting/functions";
   │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  node_modules/@material/image-list/_mixins.scss 21:9         @import
  node_modules/@material/image-list/mdc-image-list.scss 21:9  @import
  stdin 2:9                                                   root stylesheet
```

I followed the installation steps here https://material.io/develop/web/components/image-lists/ but I still get this error. I tried removing *node_modules* and npm installing again. I'm not sure if there is something wrong with my sass-loader because I used Material's Layout Grid, imported `@import "@material/layout-grid/mdc-layout-grid";` and it's working fine. What could go wrong?

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz demo?

Answer (score 3):

Add `node_modules` to the style preprocessor options in `angular.json`, so that the import path can be resolved:

```js
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
  "includePaths": [
    "./src/styles",
    "./node_modules"
  ]
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add ~ before every import in the node_modules of material so it goes `@import "@material/feature-targeting/functions";`

become `~@material/feature-targeting/functions"` 
and do so whenever the compiler shows this error